# Where to put the class="print" command in order to print a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table on my website printable (http://skagitkids.net/calendar.html). I was able to create a print.css file and put the commands in my page code. The good thing is that when the print button is clicked on, it prints the table. The bad thing is it puts a huge amount of white space before it so the table ends up being 2 pages. Actually 3 pages because it also prints out a blank 3rd page. Am I putting the code in the wrong place?

Thank you for any and all help!!

Here's the portion of the code that I put the command in:

```
<div id="layer4" style="position: absolute; left: 221px; top: 1265px; width: 884px; height: 1504px; z-index: 4">
<table class="print" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:
collapse;width:652pt" width="867" x:str="">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1609;width:33pt" width="44" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:2925;width:60pt" width="80" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:2523;width:52pt" width="69" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:7826;width:161pt" width="214" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:7680;width:158pt" width="210" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:6144;width:126pt" width="168" />
        <col style="mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:2998;width:62pt" width="82" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr height="27" style="height:20.25pt">
        <td class="auto-style3" colspan="4" height="27" style="height: 20.25pt; mso-ignore: colspan; width: 306pt" width="407">
        July 2011 Calendar</td>
        <td style="width:158pt" width="210"></td>
        <td style="width:126pt" width="168"></td>
        <td style="width:62pt" width="82"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="17" style="height:12.75pt">
        <td class="auto-style4" height="17" style="height: 12.75pt">Date</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">Week Day</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">Time</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">Activity</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">Location</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">Cost</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">Age Range</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="17" style="height:12.75pt">
        <td align="right" class="auto-style5" height="17" style="height: 12.75pt;" x:num="">
        15</td>
        <td class="auto-style6">Friday</td>
        <td class="auto-style7">10:30am</td>
        <td class="auto-style5">
        <a href="http://www.lclib.lib.wa.us/programs.htm">
        <span style="color:windowtext;
```

etc,etc, etc!

Comment: The last time I ever heard parts of HTML being referred to as commands was 10 years ago. I'm getting chills all over now :(

Comment: 1. @Bolt- don't you Program in the HTML language? (from a recent resume for someone we chose not to interview) -- 2. "mso-width-source" ... ewwwww. @Tiffany, this was all generated not hand-written. (mso = microsoft office stuff)

Comment: @Stephen P: I don't program in it. All I do with it is lay out page structures.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a separate stylesheet for your print render, like so:

```
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" />
```

Then it can look one way on your screen, and another way on paper. This is ideal for removing excess margins, padding, distracting colors, making changes to font families, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `layer4` div has inline styles that are positioning it down and to the left. To override this in your `print.css`, you can add:

```
#layer4 {
    position: relative !important; 
    left: 10px !important; 
    top: 10px !important; 
    height: auto !important;
}
```

If you instead put your inline styles (`style="position: absolute; left: 221px; top: 1265px; width: 884px; height: 1504px; z-index: 4"`) into a separate css stylesheet as suggested by AlienWebGuy, you won't need to force overriding them with `!important`, so you can leave that part out.